# Email specific Google Sheet as PDF Attachment using Appscript

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, email-attachments

This code works perfectly, but however I want a specific sheet to be emailed as PDF attachments and NOT the current active sheet. Assume the sheet is called "sheet2"

```
function sendReport() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data").hideSheet();
  var message = {
    to: "youremail@example.com",
    subject: "Monthly sales report",
    body: "Hi team,\n\nPlease find the monthly report attached.\n\nThank you,\nBob",
    name: "Bob",
    attachments: [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("Monthly sales report")]
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data").activate();
}
```

Comment: create new spreadsheet, copy sheet of interest into new sheet, export new sheet as pdf, delete the new sheet.

Answer (score 1):

**Since you only want to send one specific sheet from the spreadsheet, it's best you first export the specific sheet and later attach it in the email.**

In order to achieve this, I suggest you make the following changes to your code:

#### Code

```
function sendReport() {
    let token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Data").hideSheet();
    let spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId();
    let sheetId = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getSheetId();
    let sheetUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + spreadsheetId + "/export?" + "format=xlsx" + "&gid=" + sheetId + "&portrait=true" + "&exportFormat=pdf";
    let request = UrlFetchApp.fetch(sheetUrl, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    });
    let content = request.getContent();
    let message = {
        to: "youremail@example.com",
        subject: "Monthly sales report",
        body: "Hi team,\n\nPlease find the monthly report attached.\n\nThank you,\nBob",
        attachments: [{
            fileName: "Monthly sales report.pdf",
            content: content,
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
        }]
    }
    MailApp.sendEmail(message);
    spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Data").activate();
}
```

#### Explanation

The above code make use of the `getId` and `getSheetId` methods in order to retrieve the id of the spreadsheet and of the "Sheet2" respectively; these ids are used in order to obtain the export link `sheetUrl` for the "Sheet2". Afterwards, a request is made using `UrlFetchApp` in order to retrieve the contents of the "Sheet2" and then they are attached in the mail message using the `attachments.content` field.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Spreadsheet Class - getId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getid);
- [Apps Script Sheet Class - getSheetId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getSheetId()).